# D3 visualization - how to automate button selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm new to D3 (and javascript) but have adapted this visualization for my purposes:

[D3 visualization](https://bl.ocks.org/MichaelCurrie/raw/5e2da378a53ea624082cb55e78fdfa05)

[The code](https://gist.github.com/MichaelCurrie/5e2da378a53ea624082cb55e78fdfa05)

How can I automate the clicking of the buttons so that the browser goes to each button on an infinite loop?

I tried using jQuery with `$("#button_id").click();` but it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the function is being called with the button's ID...

```
myBubbleChart.switchMode(buttonId);
```

The task here is relatively simple.

First, set an array with all the IDs:

```
var ids = ["all", "region", "Change", "change_vs_net_value", "assets_on_map"];
```

Then, loop through it calling `myBubbleChart.switchMode()` function. Here is a very simple way, using `d3.timeout`, to call the function every 3 seconds (and changing the buttons appearance as well):

```
var index = 0;
d3.interval(function() {
    myBubbleChart.switchMode(ids[(index++) % 5])
    d3.selectAll(".button").classed("active", function(_, i) {
        return i === index % 5 - 1;
    })
}, 3000)
```

Here is the demo bl.ocks: http://blockbuilder.org/GerardoFurtado/dfaaedf591b980c2864eb054c7b29300

Comment: Thank you! I thought there must be a simpler way

Comment: Sorry, I meant your solution is simpler than me trying to use jQuery to do it!